# Numpy: sort rows of an array by rows in another array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D array of "neighbors", and I want to re-order each row according to a corresponding row in another matrix (called "radii"). The below code works, but it uses a `for` loop over a numpy array, which I know is the incorrect way to do it. What is the correct numpy / broadcast solution to this re-ordering?

```
neighbors = np.array([[8,7,6], [3,2,1]])
radii = np.array([[0.4, 0.2, 0.1], [0.3, 0.9, 0.1]])

order = radii.argsort(axis=1)
for i in range(2):
    neighbors[i] = neighbors[i,order[i]]
print(neighbors)

# Result:
[[6 7 8]
 [1 3 2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NumPy you would write something like this:

```
>>> neighbors[np.arange(2)[:, None], order]
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [1, 3, 2]])
```

(More generally you'd write the first index as `np.arange(order.shape[0])[:, None]` instead.)

This works because `np.arange(2)[:, None]` looks like this:

```
array([[0],
       [1]])
```

and order looks like this:

```
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1]])
```

For the fancy indexing, NumPy pairs off the arrays indexing each axis. The row index `[0]` is paired with the column index `[2, 1, 0]` and the new row is created in the order this determines. Similarly for `[1]` and `[2, 0, 1]` to determine the second row.

Comment: Thanks this is great! I think you have a small typo that threw me for a minute -- on the first line, I think your last ) should be a ]